# python 3.2.3 xml.etree.cElementTree unicode character not working properly

Tags: python, xml, urllib, elementtree

I've stumbled on this particular problem with python that i cannot explain why it is happen. Lets say I have this xml snippet from a server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Get the Object if known to the system-->
<object>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <name>object1</name>
  <tags type="languages">English,Español</tags>
</object>
```

I use the following code to get it from the server:

```
temp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://someurl.com")
tree = elementTree.parse(temp)
node = tree.getroot()
```

Everything works fine until I get a special character like 'ñ' in 'Español'. Instead of printing these characters correctly i get the following in my HTML code:

```
<b>tags</b>: English,EspaÃ±ol <br/>
```

How did I get from 'ñ' to 'Ã±' ?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Pause your  coding, and read this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html - then come back and check the answers

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing UTF-8 data being interpreted as Latin 1:

```
>>> '\u00f1'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
Ã±
```

where `\u00f1` is the unicode codepoint for a latin small later n with tilde: ñ.

Your terminal is probably configured for Latin-1 display; try decoding from UTF-8:

```
print(str(tag, 'utf8'))
```

Comment: Yes, I've been on this path. I was getting the following 'Espa&#241;ol'. I tried to unescape that (with escapeXML) but still I was not changing it back to its original state. I did these following commands: 
>>> print(sys.stdout.encoding)
UTF-8
>>> print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
utf-8

So it seems like everything is on UTF-8.

Comment: Does the original XML document contain that entity (`&#241;`)? That's an HTML entity, not a XML escape (only angle brackets and the ampersand need escaping for base XML). If not, could you update your question with your code attempts so far?

Comment: No it does not contain '&#241;' as far as i can see. it has always shown the right character. I have tried so many things but i will try to add the most relevent ones to my original post.